# Comparing n strings lexicographically

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of strings that I want to perform lexicographic sort on. I am not allowed to use `Arrays.sort()` or `Collections.sort()`.

Here is the approach I have so far.

```
String[] testArray = new String[]{"London Arts", "Titanic", "Titan", "London", "Lean on", "Uptown Funk"};

long[] testAsciiArray = new long[testArray.length];

for(int i = 0; i < testArray.length, i++){
    long asciiValue = 0;
    for (char c : testArray[i].toCharArray())
        asciiValue += (int)c;
    testAsciiArray[i] = asciiValue;
}
```

I then plan to perform any of the quick sorting algorithm on the testAsciiArray.  guess the worst case performance of my algorithm is N^2 since I am looping through each character of the string so I may as well just do bubble sort.  Would that gurantee any combination of n number of arbitrary strings would be lexicographically sorted once I perform this method? Is there a better way of doing it? I was about to use hash function but I heard it does not guarantee uniqueness.

I am not allowed to use any built-in Java string comparator, this is more of an Algorithm 101 exercise. I was thinking since I know how to sort an array of N numbers, if I can find an unique string to int(or bigint) mapping function that preserves the lexicographic order  I can then solve it.

Comment: Adding ASCII values will lose the ordering, e.g. the values of `"AB"` and `"BA"` would be the same. Class `String` has method [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) that you might want to use.

Comment: Thanks dejvuth. I agree this will not work. Is there a better way to map a string to a unique number preserving the lexicograpical order?

Comment: The `asciiValue` you are computing _is_ a compression/hash function - are you expecting it to help you order the strings lexicographically?

Comment: `I was thinking […] if I can find an unique string to int [… mapping]` - no way: there are only `Integer.MAX - Integer.Min` `int` values to map the countably infinite number of `Strings` to. `[…] (or bigint) mapping function that preserves the lexicographic order […]` this should be "trivial", but I'd call using `BigInteger.compareTo()` sidestepping the issue at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to implement your custom lexicographical comparing algorithm. You can simply compare strings in order to know if one of them is lexicographically first.

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html),

> `compareTo(String anotherString)` compares two strings lexicographically.

```
if (testArray[0].compareTo(testArray[1]) >= 0))
{
    // testArray[0] is lexigraphically "bigger" or equal
} else {
    // testArray[1] is lexigraphically "bigger"
}
```

Now, you only need to apply any sorting algorithm.

For example, Bubble sort:

```
boolean swapped = true;
int j = 0;
int tmp;
while (swapped) {
    swapped = false;
    j++;
    for (int i = 0; i < testArray.length - j; i++) {                                       
          if (testArray[i] > testArray[i + 1]) {                          
                tmp = testArray[i];
                testArray[i] = testArray[i + 1];
                testArray[i + 1] = tmp;
                swapped = true;
          }
    }                
}
```

You may want to use `O(N * log(N))` sorting algorithms like QuickSort or MergeSort, but it is another question. You can find a lot of on-topic information in the Internet.

**Update:** Since you are not allowed to even use `compareTo`, you can implement a custom function, which will compare strings char by char. If one string is a full prefix of another one, then the shortest one should be first:

```
int myCompareTo(String a, String b)
{
    int aLength = a.length(), bLength = b.length();
    int minLength = Math.min(aLength, bLength);

    for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++)
    {
        if (a.charAt(i) > b.charAt(i)) return 1;    
        if (a.charAt(i) < b.charAt(i)) return -1;
    }

    if (aLength > bLength) return 1;
    if (aLength < bLength) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately,I am not allowed to use any built-in compareTo function either unless I implement one myself.

Comment: @brotherofmysister Oh, you only said about `Arrays.sort() or Collections.sort().` in your question :)